# Python implementation of the paper "One Millisecond Face Alignment with an Ensemble of Regression Trees"

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, dlib

I want to build a model to predict facial landmark in real-time like the one in dlib does, which is based on the paper "One Millisecond Face Alignment with an Ensemble of Regression Trees". So is there a python implementation of the algorithm available online?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, here is the [link](https://github.com/JiaShun-Xiao/face-alignment-ert-2D)

Comment: Thank you @Ahmet

Answer (score 1):

Dlib's 68 landmark function is based on the paper "One Millisecond Face Alignment with an Ensemble of Regression Trees".
Here is a link for your reference: http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html